# Open Terminal with Java and execute "java -jar"

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to create an executable .jar that re-opens itself in Mac's Terminal console. (for the sake of having a user interface to enter commands into the program)

```
// if program is not open in Terminal:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar \"" + path + "\" isInConsole");
System.exit(0);
```

This code executes the command successfully but seamlessly so I don't get the console UI. How can I make it open a visible Terminal window and execute a command in it?

EDIT: I managed to open the Terminal, but still need to figure out how to run the `java -jar ...` command in it.

This works:

```
String arg = "cd /Users/potato/Desktop";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal --args " + arg);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
String arg = "java -jar /Users/potato/Desktop/test.jar isInConsole";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Terminal --args " + arg);
```

Comment: Well Terminal is an app and lives under /Applications/Utilities/ to start with

Comment: If your end goal is to execute a bash command or script then you should probably forget about running Terminal and look at the `ProcessBuilder` class instead to execute your command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726001/how-to-run-mac-os-terminal-commands-from-java-using-runtime

Comment: @JoakimDanielson My end goal is to re-open my executable jar inside a Terminal window for the sake of using the console to interact with my program.

Comment: You probably will need to use AppleScript to launch the Terminal.app and then run your program inside it. See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033606 . You're probably better off *not* trying to do all this from an executable jar. For a simple use case, just stick the jar in a known location somewhere, and write a shell script to launch it and put that shell script on your desktop instead.

Comment: Thank you @DanielPryden using AppleScript solved my problem

Comment: Though I didn't use a shell script file, see my answer to see how I made the .jar executable open itself in Terminal using AppleScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I ended up using executes some AppleScript code: (as DanielPryden suggested)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    if(args.length == 0 && System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac")){
        try {
            String path = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getAbsolutePath();
            String command = "tell application \"Terminal\"\n" + 
                    "do script \"java -jar \'" + path + "\' isInConsole\"\n" + 
                    "close the front window\n" + // because "do script..." opens another window
                    "activate\n" + 
                    "end tell";
            String[] arguments = new String[]{"osascript", "-e", command};

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arguments);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // program continues...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating processes, class `Runtime` has been superseded by class `ProcessBuilder`. A very old but still relevant article regarding class `Runtime` (because it was published before addition of class `ProcessBuilder` to JDK) is [When runtime.exec() won't](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) and is also relevant for class `ProcessBuilder`.

As stated in the article, method `exec()` is not a "shell" and so does not parse the command you give it as a single `String` parameter. You can help the method with parsing by providing an array of `String`s.

I suggest you read the article and also the *javadoc* for class `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.